# NodeJS child.exec bash argument is empty

Tags: node.js, bash, async-await, promise, child-process

I'm running a script like so:

```js
const someString = "text@ip:ip,text@ip:,";
const arg2 = "5";
let result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        child.exec(`"/path/to/script.sh" "${someString}" "${arg2}"`,
        (error=child.ExecException, stdout=string, stderr=string) => {
            if (error) {
                isErr = true;
                reject(error);
            }else {
                resolve(stdout); 
            }
        });
    });
```

The script receives `arg2` fine as `$2`. However, `$1` shows a blank string. I've logged the string in my Node.js app and it is correct. Possibly something to do with special characters in the string?

The script need to be run asynchronously relative to the application and synchronously relative to it's parent function(which is the case in the code snippet above).

EDIT:
Here is the original code that I can't get working. It is to dynamically generate an ansible inventory.

nodejs:

```js
async function buildInventory(site){
    const agentNumber = site.agentData.agentNumber;
    let hostsByType = {};
    let hosts = "";
    if ( site.hosts.length > 0 ){
        site.hosts.forEach(host => {
            if (hostsByType.hasOwnProperty(`${host.type}`)) {
                hostsByType[`${host.type}`].push(`${host.ip}`);
            }else{
                hostsByType[`${host.type}`] = [ `${host.ip}` ];
            }
        });
    }
    if ( hostsByType != {} ){
        for (const key in hostsByType) { // create arg in format type@ip:,type@ip:ip:,
        if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(hostsByType, key)) {
            hosts = hosts + `${key}@`;
            hostsByType[key].forEach(ip => {
                hosts = hosts + `${ip}:`;
            });
            hosts = hosts + ',';
        }
        console.log(hosts); // string logged is in expected format
    }
}
    if ( hosts = "" ){
        hosts = "na";
    }
    let isErr = false;
    let result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        child.exec(`"/usr/raindrop/app/ansible/mkinv" "${hosts}" "${agentNumber}"`,
        (error=child.ExecException, stdout=string, stderr=string) => {
            if (error) {
                isErr = true;
                reject(error);
            }else {
                resolve(stdout); 
            }
        });
    });
    if( !isErr ){
        result = result.split(/\r?\n/)[0];
        if ( result == "genskipped" ){
            logger.log('info', `Inventory generation skipped(no hosts)`);
            return true;
        }else if ( result == "gensuccess"){
            logger.log('info', `Inventory generated`);
            return true;
        }else {
            logger.log('warn', `Unknown response from inventory generation script`);
            console.log(result);
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        logger.log('error', `Inventory generation error: ${result}`);
        return false;
    }
}
```

bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /data/ansible/$2
cd /data/ansible/$2
while [[ $1 == "na" ]];do
    echo "genskip"
    exit 0;
done
touch inventory.yml
echo "all:" > inventory.yml
echo "  children:" >> inventory.yml
IFS=',' read -a hostsByType <<< "$1" # arg in format type@ip:,type@ip:ip:,
echo $1 >> /logs/ansible-debug.log
for val in "$hostsByType";do
    while [[ "$val" != "" ]];do
        IFS='@' read -a data <<< "$val"
        echo "    ${data[0]}:" >> inventory.yml
        IFS=':' read -a hosts <<< "${data[1]}"
        c=1
        for host in "$hosts";do
            while [[ "$host" != "" ]];do
              echo "      host${c}: $host"
              c=$(($c + 1))
              break;
            done
        done
      break;
    done
done
subnet=$(cat /data/vpn/rain.conf | grep 'ipv4=')
IFS='=' read -a arr <<< $subnet
subnet=${arr[1]}
agent_ip="${subnet}${2}"
echo "  vars:"  >> inventory.yml
echo "    ansible_port: 22" >> inventory.yml
echo "    ansible_user: sisadm" >> inventory.yml
echo "    private_key_file: /data/ssh/keys/$2" >> inventory.yml
echo "    ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand=\"ssh -o \'ForwardAgent yes\' agent@$agent_ip -p 11522 \'ssh-add /home/agent/.ssh/id_rsa && nc %h %p\'\"'" >> inventory.yml
echo "gensuccess"
```

EDIT2:
`/logs/ansible-debug.log` shows a new line every time the script is run.
The inventory.yml the script creates:

```yaml
all:
  children:
  vars:
    ansible_port: 22
    ansible_user: sisadm
    private_key_file: /data/ssh/keys/2
    ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand="ssh -o \'ForwardAgent yes\' agent@10.0.0.2 -p 11522 \'ssh-add /home/agent/.ssh/id_rsa && nc %h %p\'"'
```

Comment: Can't reproduce with your example.

Comment: @robertklep Added full code snippets, thanks.

Comment: off-topic, but why not use nodejs to generate the inventory in yaml format instead of the shell script?

Comment: @criztovyl Sometimes my head is too deep in the project... This is a valid answer and I may just. However, I've been trying to avoid the use of filesystem in nodejs. Bash handling files is a much cleaner operation in my opinion. I'm also able to more easily audit the use of io of the application(slightly primitive approach maybe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
if ( hosts = "" ){
    hosts = "na";
}
```

Try this:

```
if ( hosts == "" ){
    hosts = "na";
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. Many thanks to your keen eye! I presume this is expected behavior as there was no error thrown? The if condition runs if invalid, I was not aware.

Comment: The condition re-assigns the variable to `""`. The `if ("")` evaluates to false, thus not setting `hosts="na"`. A good practice (that I don't observe, ... but it's a good habit to take ...), would be to use `if ("" == hosts)` instead. As here, forgetting an `=` would have thrown.